# Modified By System Dynamic CRM 2015

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am using Dynamic CRM 2015 On-Premises and currently facing an issue related to Modified By field of account.
The issue is that whenever someone modifies or assign the account to another user, the Modified By field of the account shows "System".It should be showing the name of the person who modifies the account.
I have also checked the registered plugins,there is no code written that is responsible for this kind of functionality.
Any kind of help/suggestion will appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked workflows?  You could also turn on auditing for the entity to see if any other fields are being changed which might give you a better clue as to where the change is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If you have plugins, make sure that they are running in the current user's context. Plugins can be set to run as specific users, mostly to allow elevated permissions.

You do this by editing the Plugin Step (screenshot below).

[image: Plugin User Context]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man but i have checked each of the plugins that are running especially on the account entity and they are running in Calling User context.